# load the GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin and predict_output_word

Tags: word2vec

I tried to load the GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin and try the predict_output_word method,

I tested three ways, but every failed, the code and error of each way are shown below.

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
```

1. The first:

I first used this line:

```
model=Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',binary=True)


print(model.wv.predict_output_word(['king','man'],topn=10))
```

error:

```
DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.
```

2. The second:

Then I tried:

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',binary=True)


print(model.wv.predict_output_word(['king','man'],topn=10))
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'Word2VecKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'predict_output_word'
```

3. The third:
   model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin')
   print(model.wv.predict_output_word(['king','man'],topn=10))

error:
    _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '3'.

I read the document at

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

but still have no idea the namespace where the predict_output_word would be in.

Anybody can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `GoogleNews` set of vectors is just the raw vectors – without a full trained model (including internal weights). So it:

- can't be loaded as a fully-functional `gensim` `Word2Vec` model
- can be loaded as a lookup-only `KeyedVectors`, but that object alone doesn't have the data or protocols necessary for further model training or other functionality

Google hasn't released the full model that was used to create the `GoogleNews` vector set.

Note also that the `predict_output_word()` function in `gensim` should be considered an experimental curiosity. It doesn't work in hierarchical-softmax models (because it's not as simple to generate ranked predictions). It doesn't quite match the same context-window weighting as is used during training.

Predicting words isn't really the point of the word2vec algorithm – and many imeplementations don't offer any interface for making individual word-predictions outside of the sparse bulk training process. Rather, word2vec uses the exercise of (sloppily) trying to make predictions to train word-vectors that turn out to be useful for other, non-word-prediction, purposes.